# Null value not reflecting entire data column related party is blank than it doesn't show any output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

in the below code if value in any column is null than output is not. Coming... For example if column related party is blank than it doesn't show any output and if all column has value than it reflect output.

```
select distinct 
  vsor.shipment_gid,
  vsor.order_release_gid,
  orem1.remark_text as Related_Party,
  orem2.remark_text as ULTIMATE_CONSIGNEE_TYPE,
  orem3.remark_text as CONSIGNEE_TYPE
from 
  order_release_remark orem1,
  order_release_remark orem2,
  order_release_remark orem3,
  view_shipment_order_release vsor
--order_release_gid in('GECORP.18460727','GECORP.18435030','GECORP.18439869')
where 
  orem1.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.CONSIGNEE TYPE'
  and orem1.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and orem2.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.RELATED PARTY' 
  and orem2.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and orem3.REMARK_QUAL_GID ='GECORP.ULTIMATE CONSIGNEE TYPE'
  and orem3.order_release_gid=vsor.order_release_gid
  and vsor.shipment_gid='GECORP.101027274';
```

Comment: Please, try to improve your question, we can't understand what's the problem (help yourself with google translate if you're not good enough in english)

Comment: I have updated can you help now

Comment: use left join instead. left join will display data in vsor table even if remark text is blank

Comment: Can you please give the code with little. Modification